# AWS Cognito: Getting error in Auth.signIn (Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js has been linked)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm new to Amplify integration with Cognito and working on a react-native app using Amplify with Cognito for Authentication. I have configured the user pool and Federated Identity in the AWS console.

I have created my own signup and login interface with the respective screens using the react-navigation 5.x version.
Below are the AWS related modules I added in package.json

```
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.4.24",
"@aws-amplify/core": "^3.8.16",
```

Here is the Amplify configuration in the App.js

```
 Amplify.configure({ 
  Auth: { 
    identityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    region: 'eu-west-2',
    userPoolId: 'eu-west-2_xxxxxxxx',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
  }
});
```

I'm able to successfully invoke ***Auth.signUp*** but getting error when I'm trying to invoke ***Auth.signIn(username, password)***

> Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js has been linked

How do I able to invoke Auth.signIn successfully, please help in resolving the issue?

Comment: You need `amazon-cognito-identity-js` dependency installed.

Comment: Thanks that it helped to resolve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fix it by installing cognito identity.
Run the following:

`npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js`

After install start again rn

`npm start`

Comment: please edit your question and add more information about your errors, logs, and codes.

Comment: npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js  this work for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on ios, in addition to installing `amazon-cognito-identity-js` as mentioned, remember to also run `pod install`